# Support several types of live tiles

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I what to have square and wile tiles in my app. But when I update for example wide live tile square live tile becomes default app tile. And when I update wide square tile wide tile becomes default.

code for wide tile update

```
    var TileMgr = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();


            var tileTemplate = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Image);            
            XmlElement tmp = tileTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("visual")[0] as XmlElement;
            tmp.SetAttribute("branding", "none");
            var tileImageAttributes = tileTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            tmp = tileImageAttributes[0] as XmlElement;
            tmp.SetAttribute("src", "UpdatedLiveTileWide.png");
            var notification = new TileNotification(tileTemplate);
            TileMgr.Update( notification);
```

code for square tile update

```
 var TileMgr = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();

            var tileTemplate = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);
            XmlElement tmp = tileTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("visual")[0] as XmlElement;
            tmp.SetAttribute("branding", "none");
            var tileImageAttributes = tileTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            tmp = tileImageAttributes[0] as XmlElement;
            tmp.SetAttribute("src", "UpdatedLiveTile.png");
            var notification = new TileNotification(tileTemplate);
            TileMgr.Update(notification);
```

When I execute "code for square tile update" I get such sqare tile:

[image]

And such wide tile

[image]

After that I execute "code for wide tile update"
and get such wide tile:

[image]

and such square tile:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by square/wide tile becomes default? Does the square/wide tile gets pinned when you pin the app to Start (i.e. the "Default Size" setting in Visual Assets tab of manifest)?

Comment: I mean that tile image change to image that I set in manifest. Yes it gets pinned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating more than one type of tile, you need to do it in a single `TileNotification`. Any tile information not set in a `TileNotification` will be reset to default. To do this, you need to create the `XmlDocument` such that it has different 'binding' elements (corresponding to each type of tile) under one 'visual' element.

In your case it should be like this

```
//Create medium tile update
XmlDocument mediumTemplate = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);
(mediumTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as XmlElement).SetAttribute("src", "UpdatedLiveTile.png");

//Create wide tile update
XmlDocument wideTemplate = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Image);
(wideTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as XmlElement).SetAttribute("src", "UpdatedLiveTileWide.png");

//Import the 'binding' node from wideTemplate
var wideBinding = mediumTemplate.ImportNode(wideTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("binding")[0], true);

//Add it under 'visual' node in mediumTemplate
var visualElement = mediumTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("visual")[0];
visualElement.AppendChild(wideBinding);
(visualElement as XmlElement).SetAttribute("branding", "none");

//Now the mediumTemplate has bindings for both medium and wide tile
//Create tile notification using mediumTemplate and update
TileNotification notification = new TileNotification(mediumTemplate);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
```